# Stuck on this Python program

Tags: python

[Image to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGIOW.png)

The for loop works, though I can't figure out how to put the grade on a single line as shown in the photo. It asks for grades individualy when ran instead.

Here is my code:

```
num_students = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))
scores = []
for i in range(num_students):
    scores.append(int(input("Enter a score: ")))
best_score = max(scores)
for i in range(num_students):
    if scores[i] >= best_score - 10:
        grade = "A"
    elif scores[i] >= best_score - 20:
        grade = "B"
    elif scores[i] >= best_score - 30:
        grade = "C"
    elif scores[i] >= best_score - 40:
        grade = "D"
    else:
        grade = "F"
    print("Student", i, "score is", scores[i], "and grade is", grade)
```

Comment: Define a function which takes the score as an argument and returns the grade as a character or enum. But, this still isn't a one-line solution. What's the fascination with one-line solutions? Especially with Python? But, even with C. It's all binary that's decoded.

Comment: @MichaelRuth You misunderstand the meaning of "one line" here.  They are asking how the user can enter all the scores in _one line of input_, as shown in the image.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic] and how to create a [mre]. This question is better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) given that the code _does_ work.

Comment: The problem is that you're starting your loop too soon. Rather than asking for the scores in the loop, ask for the scores and then `split()` the input on whitespace, then loop over the resulting list

Comment: @JohnGordon, thanks for clarifying. I didn't even consider the image because it's an image and a [pain in the posterior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `input()` call instead of a loop, and use `.split()` to get each individual score.

```
num_students = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))
scores = input(f"Enter {num_students} scores: ")
scores = [int(score) for score in scores.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

As John Gordon answered, your main issue is calling input inside a loop. That dictates that each user response will be on its own line. To fix this, call input once, then break the resulting string up using .split(). Split when called with no arguments will break a string into a list at each space.

Here is an example of how to do this (without the f strings and list comprehensions from John's answer):

```py
num_students = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))
score_string = input("Enter " + str(num_students) + " scores: ")

scores = []
for score in score_string.split():
    scores.append(int(score))
```